# Generating i18n translation file for multicomponent Angular application

Tags: angular, angular-i18n

I have an application developed with several components (.ts and .html). When I try to generate Xlif translation file with ng xi18n, only one component seems to be scanned, and translation sources for all other components are not in the xlif generated file.

Any idea or suggestions? Or is this a limitation of Angular CLI?

Many thanks

Comment: All should be there. Have you used `i18n` everywhere? Also, for Typescript files, you might need to add polyfill https://github.com/ngx-translate/i18n-polyfill. If you show code examples we might be able the help more

Comment: Hi Bojan - thanks for your help - indeed I used a script to insert i18n in other files but there was a typo (i18 only). Your reply helped to me focus on the real issue. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question:  I used a script to insert i18n in other files but there was a typo (i18 only). Once corrected, translation sources were generated for all components of the project.